# Merging 2 Processes -> parent adopting a child

Tags: process, parent-child, encapsulation, lifecycle, late-binding

Init can reap orphaned processes. Zombies can cause issues with system resources.  These are situations where UNIX/Linux can and has done a good job over the years.

With the advent of Docker/Kubernetes, Podman, and other container-based clusters. Managing dependencies between related processes are critical for the horizontal scaling of a system. The logic for each microservice is required to be encapsulated within the service itself. Systems morph over time, functionality, interfaces, inter-dependencies change -- the microservice loses its encapsulation. Horizontal scaling is severely impacted, if not entirely muted.

What if you could write a plugin, launch it and it could stand-alone or it could bind/detach to/from a parent process in real-time as the run-time state requires?

Tightly bound, it could easily extend the parent's capabilities.

What if it could morph the parent too?

Over the life-cycle of the process, could real-time dynamic process adaptation guarantee all-new inter-dependencies would be encapsulated?

If so, existing processes could be extended in novel ways without any new code developed for the parent.

Does anyone know how a parent process can attach/detach a child process using the UNIX/Linux OS?